# How can I pass a variable to an onClick event handler?

Tags: javascript, html

I'd like to create some buttons each of which has a different argument passed to its onclick handler.

Here is what I have so far:

```
$.each(Object.keys(all_sockets_rooms[his_username]["rooms"]), function (key, room_name) {
    $("#myrooms").append("<button name='"+room_name+"' onclick='join(\'"+room_name+"\')'>"+room_name+"</button>");
});
```

Comment: have you tried using double quote in your 'join("somestring")' ?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have valid escape sequence!

Try this:

```js
$.each(Object.keys(all_sockets_rooms[his_username]["rooms"]), function(key, room_name) {
  $("#myrooms").append("<button name='" + room_name + "' onclick='join(\"" + room_name + "\")'>" + room_name + "</button>");
});
```